# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Heres the where the error happened the LG(); is a String from API

```
Status() {
  String rawJson =
      LG();
  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be like this

```dart
Future Status() async{
  String rawJson =
     await LG();
  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
}
```